# Replace pointer in keysquare with letters in string

Tags: python

I have this keysquare:

```
keysquare = {'?': 'AA', '?': 'AD', '?': 'AF', '?': 'AG', '?': 'AV', '?': 'AX',
             '?': 'DA', '?': 'DD', '?': 'DF', '?': 'DG', '?': 'DV', '?': 'DX',
             '?': 'FA', '?': 'FD', '?': 'FF', '?': 'FG', '?': 'FV', '?': 'FX',
             '?': 'GA', '?': 'GD', '?': 'GF', '?': 'GG', '?': 'GV', '?': 'GX',
             '?': 'VA', '?': 'VD', '?': 'VF', '?': 'VG', '?': 'VV', '?': 'VX',
             '?': 'XA', '?': 'XD', '?': 'XF', '?': 'XG', '?': 'XV', '?': 'XX'}
```

What I want is to replace each `?` with the follow string `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`, letter by letter if it's possible.

Like first `?` = A, second `?` = B, etc...

Comment: What is a keysquare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `itertools.product` and `zip`:

```py
from itertools import product

keys = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
values = [''.join(_) for _ in product('ADFGVX', 'ADFGVX')]

kv = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(kv)
```

The code above will give you the following output (formated by me for better visibility):

```py
{'A': 'AA', 'B': 'AD', 'C': 'AF', 'D': 'AG', 'E': 'AV', 'F': 'AX',
 'G': 'DA', 'H': 'DD', 'I': 'DF', 'J': 'DG', 'K': 'DV', 'L': 'DX',
 'M': 'FA', 'N': 'FD', 'O': 'FF', 'P': 'FG', 'Q': 'FV', 'R': 'FX',
 'S': 'GA', 'T': 'GD', 'U': 'GF', 'V': 'GG', 'W': 'GV', 'X': 'GX',
 'Y': 'VA', 'Z': 'VD', '1': 'VF', '2': 'VG', '3': 'VV', '4': 'VX',
 '5': 'XA', '6': 'XD', '7': 'XF', '8': 'XG', '9': 'XV', '0': 'XX'}
```

You can even do it in just one step with something like this:

```py
from itertools import product

kv = dict(
    zip(
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',
        (''.join(_) for _ in product('ADFGVX', 'ADFGVX'))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a valid dictionary as it has duplicate keys "?".
However, if you had a dictionary with your keys and values flipped, you could do something like this (Assuming the order in the dict is preserved)

```
# remember to create a valid dict
# keysquare = {'AA': '?', 'AD': '?' ...}

keys = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
len_keys = len(keys)
new_keysquare = {keysquare[key]: keys[i % len_keys] for i, key in enumerate(keysquare)}

print(new_keysquare)
```